# set default display:none for a section of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting to set the paragraph to "display:none" on initial opening of the HTML file. Then use javascript code to show/hide it.
This is what I have written so far

HTML:

```
<hide1 class="inner" style="display.none;">
    <p>hello</p>
</hide1>
```

JavaScript:

```
function tr1(obj)
    {
    var inner = document.getElementsByTagName("hide1")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Hello shows when i open the file and then toggles from shown to hidden. I would like it to be hidden by default and toggle from hidden to shown.

Comment: Hint :try alert(inner.style.display) before if condition , see what it gives

Comment: *"I am wanting to set the paragraph to "display:none" on initial opening of the HTML file*" Then you should do that. Currently you are writing `display.none`, which is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display.none;` it's not correct way to assign the inline style.

Use `display:none;` instead of using  `display.none;`.

```
<hide1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <p>hello</p>
</hide1>
```

**Note: `<hide1></hide1>` it's not a valid html tag.**

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="toggle()">
```

Jquery

```
function toggle(){
 $('.inner').toggle();
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qkuZ/1/)

Comment: When I add the colon I cannot toggle it with the JS code?

Comment: @user3733200: Of course you can.

Comment: Yes, you can (@Felix Kling is right)

Comment: Sorry, i changed something else without realising it which broke the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<hide1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <p>hello</p>
</hide1>
```

**display:none** would do the trick for you

**EDIT**
Use the below function to toggle visibility

```
function toggle(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
}
```

/* Based on your question, In your case, e1 = document.getElementsByTagName("hide1")[0]; */

Basic IDEA Behind is:

```
// showing
 document.getElementById('element').style.display = '';

// hiding
document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none';
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
function toggle() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("hide1")[0];
    el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
}
```

Comment: When I add the colon I cannot toggle it with the JS code?

Comment: yeah!! That code needs to be changed too.. Wait i will post

Comment: @user3733200: Refer edit. I have added logic for toggle and a small explanation too..

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia:- I was about to edit the same change. +1

Comment: I cant get the Javascript to work :/ @NishanthiGrashia

Comment: @user3733200: Refer the EDIT AGAIN part. It is working and I checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
<hide1 class="inner">
    <p>hello</p>
</hide1>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.link').on( 'click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
    if($('.inner').is(':visible')){
        $('.inner').hide();
    }
    else
    {
         $('.inner').show();
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.inner{
    display:none;
}
```

You are missing **':'** inside css style.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CXc49/